# how to use ngFor result in other elements?

Tags: angular, typescript

Ive used this template to print search result by `ngFor` and have result count before list:

```
Found 1 result for **test**

test title
```

the template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div [ngSwitch]="resultCounter">
        <h6 class="my-5" *ngSwitchCase="'0'">There is no data about {{ searchedPhrase }}!</h6>
        <h6 class="my-5" *ngSwitchCase="'1'">Found {{ resultCounter }} result for <strong>{{ searchedPhrase }}</strong></h6>
        <h6 class="my-5" *ngSwitchDefault>Found {{ resultCounter }} results for <strong>{{ searchedPhrase }}</strong></h6>
    </div>

    <ul class="search-result">
        <li *ngFor="let item of dataset | searchFilter:searchedPhrase:'title' as total; index as i" class="py-2">
            <p [title]="getResultCount(i)">{{ item.title }}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and typescript:

```
  searchedPhrase: string;
  resultCounter: number;

  getResultCount(i) {
      this.resultCounter = i + 1;
  }
```

but I get this error that means the wrong way to pass data for out of *ngFor scope:

```
ERROR Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngSwitch: undefined'. Current value: 'ngSwitch: 1'."
```

Comment: first time `resultCounter` value is undefined so you have to pass default value in `this.resultCounter = 0` check with this

Comment: Remove resultCounter and getResultCount from your component. Use `i + 1` in the template to know the current index, and `total.length` to know the number of filtered results. You can't modify the state of your component at every iteration of ngFor as you're trying to do.

Comment: I agree with your comment about total.length but about removing getResultCount function because for access the ```ngFor``` data out of its scope it is good way to pass it by typescript. for now the passing process works correctly but the main problem is ```ngFor``` process continues till last item and it will update ```resultCounter``` after first printing